# jQuery after empty() an element then append() to it again, how to trigger click event on the appended element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the code below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button-group01">
    <input type="radio" id="btn01" name="group01" value="type1"> <label for="btn01">type1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="btn02" name="group01" value="type2"> <label for="btn02">type2</label>
</div>
<div class="button-group02"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    function One(deferred) {
        $('.button-group01 input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e){
            let tar = $('.button-group02');
            tar.empty();
            if ( $(this).val() == "type1" ) {
                tar.append(' <input type="radio" id="btn04" name="group02" value="type1-1"> <label for="btn04">type1-1</label>');
                tar.append(' <input type="radio" id="btn05" name="group02" value="type1-2"> <label for="btn05">type1-2</label>');
            }
            else if ( $(this).val() == "type2" ) {
                tar.append(' <input type="radio" id="btn04" name="group02" value="type2-1"> <label for="btn04">type2-1</label>');
                tar.append(' <input type="radio" id="btn05" name="group02" value="type2-2"> <label for="btn05">type2-2</label>');
            }
            if (deferred !== undefined) { deferred.resolve(); }
        });
    }
    function Two(deferred) {
        $('.button-group02 input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e){
            let tar = $('.result');
            tar.empty();
            tar.append('<p>result is: '+$(this).val()+'</p>');
            if (deferred !== undefined) { deferred.resolve(); }
        });
    }
    function Three(deferred) {
        // ...
    }

    function run() {
        let defer1 = $.Deferred();
        let defer2 = $.Deferred();
        One(defer1);
        $.when(defer1).done(function () {
            Two(defer2);
        });
        $.when(defer2).done(function () {
            Three();
        });
    }
    run();
});
```

Using deferred to append 2 step on click. After click on `.button-group02` the `.result` will show the final result.

I want to make the final result changeable after switching between choice.

But the problem is if i switch between `.button-group01` choice, `click` event on function `Two()` will not fire anymore because of the `tar.empty()` call on `One()`.

How do i fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to do with your use of deferred. Once the promise is resolved, that's it, the deferred object is finished. That means that after the first set of radio buttons is clicked on once, Two() is called but never again. Otherwise your code is fine.

A very simple solution in your code is to change this line in One():

```
if (deferred !== undefined) { deferred.resolve(); }
```

To simply

```
Two();
```

As in this snippet:

```js
$(function(){
    function One() {
        $('.button-group01 input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e){
            let tar = $('.button-group02');
            tar.empty();
            if ( $(this).val() == "type1" ) {
                tar.append(' <input type="radio" id="btn04" name="group02" value="type1-1"> <label for="btn04">type1-1</label>');
                tar.append(' <input type="radio" id="btn05" name="group02" value="type1-2"> <label for="btn05">type1-2</label>');
            }
            else if ( $(this).val() == "type2" ) {
                tar.append(' <input type="radio" id="btn04" name="group02" value="type2-1"> <label for="btn04">type2-1</label>');
                tar.append(' <input type="radio" id="btn05" name="group02" value="type2-2"> <label for="btn05">type2-2</label>');
            }
            Two();
        });
    }
    function Two() {
        $('.button-group02 input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e){
            let tar = $('.result');
            tar.empty();
            tar.append('<p>result is: '+$(this).val()+'</p>');
        });
    }
    function Three(deferred) {
    }

    function run() {
        let defer1 = $.Deferred();
        let defer2 = $.Deferred();
        One();
        /* $.when(defer1).done(function () {
            Two(defer2);
        });
        $.when(defer2).done(function () {
            Three();
        }); */
    }
    run();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group01">
    <input type="radio" id="btn01" name="group01" value="type1"> <label for="btn01">type1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="btn02" name="group01" value="type2"> <label for="btn02">type2</label>
</div>
<div class="button-group02"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

But I imagine there may be a reason you'd rather use promises. Well, if you're anticipating a stream of promises (as in this case) you might want to consider using Observables and RxJS:

https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview

I've never used RxJS in Jquery but this page seems to deal with that problem:

https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/how_do_i/jquery_with_rxjs.html

If you're not so keen on learning rxjs, and don't want to hardcode the function calls within each function, I'd consider using callbacks instead.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. I didn't know it was so simple.

RxJS is interesting but i don't want to use external library other than jQuery itself.

And it's true this's just a simple demo for my question, i will try to apply this solution to my real project tomorrow and let you know if it's worked too.

Comment: i confirm this worked on my project too. thanks @Michael